# Get data from iPhone to Apple Watch with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchkit

I am developing an iPhone app on Xamarin and have added an Apple Watch extension for watchOS 3.

I need to get data that is save on the iPhone to the watch extension.

I only need to get it once, and then save it on the watch so it can be used without the iPhone's presence. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Solved by using Iain Smith's `WCSessionManager` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the data you could use update Application Context messages. In brief, application context is best used for transferring data that always needs to be updated to the latest information. This is important because, for all of the data that you’re transferring over, only the latest copy of that data will actually appear at your final destination.

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity) once you get the message then you could save it in NSUserDefault or whatever suits.

It is written for watchOS 2.0+

`WCSessionManager` is class that handles the delegate calls have a look [here](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension/SessionManager/WCSessionManager.cs)

It is basically a singleton that helps manage the connection, so you dont have to put it in all your interface conteroller or viewcontrollers.

Its starts in [ExtensionDelegate](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension/ExtensionDelegate.cs#L14)  on the watch and in [ApplicationDelegate](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity/AppDelegate.cs#L25) on the phone.

Comment: Was this sample written for WatchOS 1? I think it changed since then, because I can't find the event `WCSessionManager.SharedManager.ApplicationContextUpdated` that you are using, instead there's the property `WatchConnectivity.WCSession.DefaultSession.ApplicationContext`. I'll investigate and keep you updated.

Comment: I have updated my answer have a look at these tutorials too http://kristina.io/watchos-2-tutorial-using-application-context-to-transfer-data-watch-connectivity-2/ https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-application-context/ on Application Context. That are in Obj-c/swift but still helpful in what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, that all helped. I found the code needed to send data to the watch  from the phone. But I can't get it to work. I added all the relevant code. Any idea why?

Comment: For the code you posted it doesnt look like you are sending any messages with the data from the phone app e.g. something like this `WCSession.DefaultSession.UpdateApplicationContext();`

Comment: In the sample this is done here in the iphone app using the WCSessionManager https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity/ViewController.cs#L46 And this is the code for it calls in the WCSession manager https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension/SessionManager/WCSessionManager.cs#L98

Comment: I couldn't find any class called `WCSessionManager` so I went with `WatchConnectivity` instead. But that's strange, cause I can't even find it on the Xamarin documentation. Maybe I missed something, I'll check again when I get back to my office tomorrow morning, or download your code and see. I didn't include this part of the code, but I am calling `WatchConnectivity.WCSession.DefaultSession.UpdateApplicationContext(new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(), out myNSError)` at a certain point in my iPhone app. I forgot to check the out error, so I'll check that too when I get back to my office.

Comment: Yeah `WCSessionManager` is a class I made for that sample https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.OnWatchExtension/SessionManager/WCSessionManager.cs it is basically a singleton that wraps the WatchConnectivity calls and is used in both the watch and iphone app (linked file) hence all the `#if __IOS__` to detect if it is the watch or phone. You would use it so that you dont need to access the static WatchConnectivityDelegate in your ExtensionDelegate as if you want to receive message on the watch you will need that in your app delegate too

Comment: OK, that makes sense now :)
I will try this, just one thing: why do you need the `[Export("session:didReceiveApplicationContext:")]` annotation?

Comment: It is a linking between c# and objC https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/registrar/ Just realised I could have subclassed `WCSessionDelegate` (rather than `NSObject` and `IWCSessionDelegate` and not needed those linkings. I'll update my sample.

Comment: I got it working with your awesome `WCSessionManager`. I feel like I should pay you by now. Just one more thing: I can't find where the `session.Paired` and `session.WatchAppInstalled` properties are. I just commented them out for now so it would compile. Are they extensions you wrote somewhere? If so, where? I can't find them anywhere..

Comment: Haha no worries glad its helping. `session.Paired` and `session.WatchAppInstalled` are properties only on the Xamarin.iOS version of `WatchConnectivity.WCSession` (there is a Xamarin.watchOS version of this class too). If you open the linked `WCSessionManager` on the iPhone Project the errors will go away but it should still build as when the watch project builds it wont have the preprocessor `__IOS__` and will skip over those lines.